# Passing an initial value into a form field from previous detail view

Tags: django, forms

I a bit confused how to do this, I have a "contact user" button on a user detail page. I am trying to set the initial form value for the email field as the users email from the previous detail page view, so that it pre-populates.

Would I pass the user.email as a kwarg into the button url?

**views.py**

```
def Contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    # new logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
            , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
            , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')

            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            }
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New contact form submission",
                content,
                "Your website" +'',
                ['youremail@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('contact_form')


    return render(request, 'portal/contact_form.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, initial='{ kwarg }')
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

**user_detail.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center p-5" style="padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">
              <a href="{% url 'portal:contact_form' kwarg.user.email %}">
                <h1><i class="fa fa-2x fa-envelope-o text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
                <p class="text-muted mt-3 ">Contact Customer</p>
              </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why not use `request.session` ? or you wanna look into how to pass variables with [kwargs](https://gist.github.com/andrefsp/5115772)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. Like for example:

#### Method 1: Send it in URL Querystring

from you previous details view, send the email in url querystring. For example:

```
 def DetailForm(request, *args, **kwargs):
      ... 
      if form.is_valid():
           # do some things
           user_email = form.cleaned_data.get('user_email')  # assuming its the form field you are using for catching user email

           redirect_url = "{}?user_email={}".format(self.get_success_url(), user_email)
           return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

And catch it in Next form view:

```
  def Contact(request):
     form_class = ContactForm(initial={'contact_email': request.GET.get('user_email')})
     ...
```

#### Method 2: Store in session.

Its almost similar to last approach, but it stores the data in [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/).

```
def DetailForm(request, *args, **kwargs):
      ... 
      if form.is_valid():
           # do some things
           request.session['user_email'] = form.cleaned_data.get('user_email')  # Storing data in session

           # every other code
```

And get it in Next form view:

```
  def Contact(request):
     form_class = ContactForm(initial={'contact_email': request.session.get('user_email')})
     ...
```

#### Update

If you are coming from a detail page, means you have the access to the object. So in the detail page, update the `contact` button like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'portal:contact_form' object.email %}">contact</a>  // or user.email if you are passing user object as user in context
```

in Contact View:

```
def Contact(request, email):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = ContactForm(initial={'contact_email': email)})
```

Comment: Why are you using a form? Do i have to use a form to pass the variable to the next view?

Comment: How are you planning to capture user email if you are not using any form or input method?

Comment: Isn't the user detail page already querying the data for that specific user?

Comment: Ah, that makes things easier. Please see my updated answer